# How to use smart pointer on default constructor

Tags: memory-management, constructor, delphi-xe2, smart-pointers

So, once again I am learning new things and I came across Smart Pointers. I had code

```
procedure TForm3.BitBtn1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  _StringList: ISmartPointer<TStringList>;
begin
  _StringList := TSmartPointer<TStringList>.Create(TStringList.Create);
end;
```

As you see variable declaration is kinda odd, and simplification is needed. I came across another solution

```
procedure TForm3.btnDelphiClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  _StringList: TStringList;
begin
  _StringList := SmartGuard.SmartGuard<TStringList>(TStringList.Create(False));
end;
```

Sadly, it does not work with parameterless constructor

```
procedure TForm3.btnDelphiClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  _StringList: TStringList;
begin
  _StringList := SmartGuard.SmartGuard<TStringList>(TStringList.Create);
end;
```

**[dcc32 Error] Main.pas(47): E2089 Invalid typecast**

Am I out of luck here?
P.S. I know some of you would argue I should stick to try..finally block, but this is out of curiosity.

```
unit SmartGuard;

interface

type
  IGuard = interface
  ['{CE522D5D-41DE-4C6F-BC84-912C2AEF66B3}']
  end;

  TGuard = class(TInterfacedObject, IGuard)
  private
    FObject: TObject;
  public
    constructor Create(AObject: TObject);
    destructor Destroy; override;
  end;

  SmartGuard<T: class> = record
  private
    FGuard: IGuard;
    FGuardedObject: T;
  public
    class operator Implicit(GuardedObject: T): SmartGuard<T>;
    class operator Implicit(Guard: SmartGuard<T>): T;
  end;

implementation

uses
  {Delphi}
  System.SysUtils
  {Project}
  ;

constructor TGuard.Create(AObject: TObject);
begin
  FObject := AObject;
end;

destructor TGuard.Destroy;
begin
  FObject.Free;
  inherited;
end;

{ SmartGuard }

class operator SmartGuard<T>.Implicit(GuardedObject: T): SmartGuard<T>;
begin
  Result.FGuard := TGuard.Create(GuardedObject);
  Result.FGuardedObject := GuardedObject;
end;

class operator SmartGuard<T>.Implicit(Guard: SmartGuard<T>): T;
begin
  Result := Guard.FGuardedObject;
end;

end.
```

I would love to find a solution that would not require additional "method" calling as in here https://github.com/marcocantu/DelphiSessions/blob/master/DelphiLanguageCodeRage2018/02_SmartPointers/SmartPointerClass.pas e.g. `_StringList.Value.Add('foo');` and "special" brackets e.g. `_StringList := TSmartPointer<TStringList>.Create(TStringList.Create)();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler needs help disambiguating

```
TStringList.Create
```

The compiler doesn't know whether this is a reference to a method, or a call to the method.

Disambiguate by adding parens to indicate that it is a call.

```
_StringList := SmartGuard.SmartGuard<TStringList>(TStringList.Create());
```